# Как программно поменять стиль в android?

Tags: android, kotlin, popup, popupmenu

я создал два стиля в которых меняется вид popup menu и когда создаю popup в зависимости от выбранной темы должны использоваться разные стили, но через setTheme() это не работает в чем проблема?

стили:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here.-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="android:popupWindowStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="android:popupTheme">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
</style>
```

код в активити:

```
private fun showPopup(view: View){ //создание меню
    if (them==1){
        getApplication().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
    }
    else if(them==2){
        getApplication().setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark)
    }
    ...
}
```

Или может можно как-то менять отдельные параметры стиля?

Comment: Возможно вам надо `recreate()` у активити вызвать после установки темы. Ну и/или делать установку темы до вызова `super.onCreate(savedState)`

Comment: Не помогло, приложение перезапускается, но стиль не меняется

Comment: Других идей у меня нет( Там как-то очень сложно эти попапы настраивать(

Comment: А нельзя ли менять какие-то отдельные параметры стиля программно?

Comment: Попробуйте вот тут ответы посмотреть: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22320663/3212712